# 302 Found while hosting page on virtualhost, Ubuntu

Tags: apache, unix, ubuntu, virtualhost

So i am trying to host a webpage on apache, ubuntu platform using virualhost concept. I made these changes so far.

- created webpage on this path /var/www/test/index.html
  contents of it are:

  $cat index.html

  Hey this is a test webpage
- created .conf file for virtualhost on this path /etc/apache2/sites-available/test.com.conf

contents of it are :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.com
        ServerAlias www.test.com
        ServerAdmin admin@test.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

- ran "sudo a2ensite test.com.conf" to enable it.
- restarted apache.

Now, when i try to curl test.com i get this wierd output from nowhere

output :

```
$ curl test.com
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.9.15</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand whats happening here, from where this webpage is coming and how should i fix it to get my desired webpage. I have not installed nginx on my machine. Please help.

Comment: your output says "nginx", maybe you could stop nginx service?

Comment: Are you actually using the domain name test.com?  Are you aware that [it already belongs to someone else](https://www.test.com/)?

Comment: Too Funny...  Guess what, they use nginx/1.9.15

Comment: Point test.com to localhost in your HOSTS file.  That will at least let you "test" your config

Comment: @Gary, thanks... worked like a charm.. i did not think in that direction :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point test.com to localhost in your HOSTS file. That will at least let you "test" your config